# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm dynamically creating components in angular. I'm working with Wavemaker on a Web App. In the preview, it is working just fine, but the deployed App returns this error.

```
var dynamicServicePerson = App.getDependency('DynamicComponentService');

function getTabsPersonAcc(acc) {
        gcp = [];
        for (var t = 0; t < acc.length; t++) {
            gcp.push("<wm-tabpane name='tabpane1000_" + c + "' title='" + acc[t] + "' backgroundcolor='#EFF3F6'>" +
                "<wm-layoutgrid name='layoutgrid1000_" + c + "'>" +
                "<wm-gridrow name='gridrow1000_" + c + "'>" +
                "<wm-gridcolumn columnwidth='12' name='gridcolumn1000_" + c + "'padding='1em' horizontalalign='center'>" +
                "<wm-tile name='tile1000_" + c + "'class='note' margin='unset unset 1em unset'>" +
                "<wm-prefab prefabname='D3_Area_Chart' name='D3_Area_Chart1" + c + "' account='" + acc[t] + "' url='https://api.myjson.com/bins/jxn53'></wm-prefab>'" +
                "</wm-tile>" + "</wm-gridcolumn>" + "</wm-gridrow>" + "</wm-layoutgrid>" + "</wm-tabpane>");
            c++;
        }
        getTabsPersonEntity(gcp);
        c = 0;
    }

function getData(num) {
 try {
            const pr = getPerson(num);
            pr.then(function(result) {
                if (result !== undefined && result.length > 0) {
                    const wait = async() => {
                        const person = await (result);
                        getTabsPersonAcc(person);
                    }
                    wait();
                } else {
                    getTabsPersonEntityNoAcc();
                }
            })
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
                console.log(e, true);
            } else {
                console.log(e, false);
            }
        }
    }

function complete() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var plgP = "<wm-layoutgrid name='layoutgrid4000_" + b + "'><wm-gridrow name='gridrow4000_" + b + "'>" +
                "<wm-gridcolumn columnwidth='12' name='gridcolumn4000_" + b + "'padding='1em'>" +
                "<wm-tabs name='tabs4000" + b + "' transition='slide'>" + tpp + "</wm-tabs></wm-gridcolumn></wm-gridrow></wm-layoutgrid>";
            try {
                dynamicServicePerson.addComponent($('[name="gridPersonEntity"]')[0], plgP, Page);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
                    console.log(e, true);
                } else {
                    console.log(e, false);
                }
            }
        }, 4000);
    }

function getTabpaneEntity() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
            try {
                var num = data[b].id;
                getData(num);
                b++;
            } catch (e) {
                if (e instanceof ReferenceError) {
                    console.log(e, true);
                } else {
                    console.log(e, false);
                }
            }
        }
        complete();
    }
    getTabpaneEntity();
```

The function checks for data in the database and returns the names of each row in the DB in an HTML tab-pane.

I'm pretty new to programming, so maybe the code is a bit rough.

Thanks

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded

```
at e.rd (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:16852)
at e.<anonymous> (main.b26322881031beaa2432.js:1)
at tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:91
at Object.next (tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:72)
at tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:65
at new e (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:910)
at s (tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:61)
at e.getComponentFactoryRef (main.b26322881031beaa2432.js:1)
at e.<anonymous> (main.b26322881031beaa2432.js:1)
at tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:91
at M (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:831)
at zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:741
at a (tslib.es6.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:63)
at t.invoke (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:391)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:17289)
at t.invoke (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:390)
at e.run (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:150)
at zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:889
at t.invokeTask (zone.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:423)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:17280)
```

Comment: Try with returning your promise. Just use `return wait();` and `return getTabsPersonEntityNoAcc();`. Maybe that helps

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. But thanks for the help.